# iPhone/iPad: save search result

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios4

This is for a prototype. Suppose I have 2 textFields on a screen. A users logs in and entered some values in those fields. I want to implement a feature so that when the user logs in next time those fields are prepopulated with the values he has entered last time.

What can be the possible ways to implement this in iPad application.

Thnx in advance.

Comment: you can save those values into a plist than then load them when the viewDidLoad method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save your user name and password in NSUserDefaults.
Use the following method in your class.

```
NSUserDefaults *user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [user setObject:userTextField.text
             forKey:@"username"];
    [user setObject:passwordTextField.text
             forKey:@"password"];
    [user synchronize];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save this values in plist or NSUserDefaults then load then in the Text field.